Copy Qty. to Produce Value for Child Production Orders in Production Order Maintenance Screen
I have a requirement as follows and need to know how this can be catered via customizing the action.
When I click on “Generate Orders for Subassemblies” for a parent item such as given below with a qty to produce of 10.00
Parent Item Production Order
When the button is pressed the child items also need to be set to a qty to produce of 10.00, currently Acumatica sets it to 1.00 as shown below
Child Items Automatically Copied and Set to 1.00
How can I also copy over the qty to produce as well over to the child items once the button is pressed? This is my code so far but I am not sure if I am overriding the action properly, any insight regarding this would be helpful, thank you!
 namespace PX.Objects.AM
{
  public class ProdMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ProdMaint.ItemLineSplittingExtension,PX.Objects.AM.ProdMaint>
  {  
 //ADD ROWINSERTED LOGIC
           protected virtual void _(Events.RowInserted<AMProdItem> e)
        {
            UpdateChildOrder(e.Cache, e.Row);
        }

        protected virtual void _(Events.RowUpdated<AMProdItem> e)
        {
            UpdateChildOrder(e.Cache, e.Row);
        }

        private void UpdateChildOrder(PXCache cache, AMProdItem row)
        {
            if (row == null || cache == null)
                return;

            // Ensure this is a child order with a valid parent
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.ParentOrdID))
                return;

            // Query the parent order using PK.Find
            var parentOrder = AMProdItem.PK.Find(Base, row.ParentOrderType, row.ParentOrdID);
            if (parentOrder == null)
                return;

            // Update the child order fields using parent order values
            cache.SetValueExt<AMProdItem.qtytoProd>(row, parentOrder.QtytoProd);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentOrder.BOMRevisionID))
            {
                cache.SetValueExt<AMProdItem.bOMRevisionID>(row, parentOrder.BOMRevisionID);
            }

            PXTrace.WriteInformation($"Child order updated: {row.ProdOrdID}, Parent: {parentOrder.ProdOrdID}, QtyToProd: {row.QtytoProd}");
        }

        
          //END OF ROW INSERTED LOGIC
  }
}


I have also tried this override method but it does not have any effect.
 namespace PX.Objects.AM
{
  public class ProdMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ProdMaint.ItemLineSplittingExtension,PX.Objects.AM.ProdMaint>
  {
 public delegate IEnumerable CreateLinkedOrdersDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);

        [PXOverride]
        public IEnumerable CreateLinkedOrders(PXAdapter adapter, CreateLinkedOrdersDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            var result = baseMethod(adapter); // Call the original logic to create child orders

            // Ensure the current production order is loaded
            if (Base.ProdMaintRecords.Current == null)
                return result;

            // Get the parent production order's QtyToProduce
            decimal? parentQtyToProduce = Base.ProdMaintRecords.Current.QtytoProd;
            string parentBOMRevisionID = Base.ProdMaintRecords.Current.BOMRevisionID;

            // Start with the first child orders
            string currentParentID = Base.ProdMaintRecords.Current.ProdOrdID;

            // Continue finding and updating children until no more are found
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentParentID))
            {
                // Find child order for current parent
                var childOrder = (AMProdItem)PXSelect<AMProdItem,
                    Where<AMProdItem.parentOrdID, Equal<Required<AMProdItem.parentOrdID>>>>
                    .Select(Base, currentParentID)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (childOrder != null && parentQtyToProduce.HasValue)
                {
                    // Update quantity for this child
                    childOrder.QtytoProd = parentQtyToProduce;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentBOMRevisionID))
                        childOrder.BOMRevisionID = parentBOMRevisionID;
                    
                    Base.ProdMaintRecords.Update(childOrder);

                    // Move to next parent in the chain
                    currentParentID = childOrder.ProdOrdID;
                }
                else
                {
                    // No more children found, exit the loop
                    break;
                }
            }

            Base.Actions.PressSave(); // Save all changes to the database

            return result;
        }      
}
}

With this code I get a null reference exception error.
Exception Type: 
System.NullReferenceException
 Message:   
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 Stack Trace:   
 at PX.Data.PXFirstChanceExceptionLogger.ProfilerFirstChanceException(Object o, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs args)
 at PX.Objects.AM.GLAccountHelper.GetAcctID[Field](PXGraph graph, String AcctDefault, InventoryItem inventoryItem, INSite site, INPostClass postClass, AMOrderType amOrderType)
 at PX.Objects.AM.GLAccountHelper.GetAccountDefaults[Field](PXGraph graph, InventoryItem inventoryItem, INSite site, INPostClass postclass, AMOrderType amOrderType)
 at PX.Objects.AM.ProdMaint.SetAccountDefaults(PXCache cache)
 at PX.Objects.AM.ProdMaint.AMProdItem_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
 at PX.Data.PXFieldUpdated.Invoke(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs args)
 at PX.Objects.AM.ProdMaint_Extension.AMProdItem_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated baseHandler)
 at PX.Data.PXCache.OnFieldUpdated(String name, Object row, Object oldValue, Boolean externalCall)
 at PX.Data.PXCache`1.FillWithValues(TNode item, TNode copy, TNode newitem)
 at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Update(Object data, Boolean bypassinterceptor)
 at PX.Data.PXSelectBase`1.Update(Table item)
 at PX.Objects.AM.CriticalMaterialsInq.CreateNewProdItem(AMProdItem parentAMProdItem, Decimal qtyToProduce, AMProdMatl prodMatl, CreateProdFilter filter, Numbering numbering, ProdMaint prodMaintGraph)
 at PX.Objects.AM.CriticalMaterialsInq.CreateProductionOrder(AMProdItem prodCreatedFrom, Decimal qtyToProduce, AMProdMatl prodMatl, CreateProdFilter filter, Numbering numbering, ProdMaint prodMaintGraph, Int32 level, List`1 ordersList, Nullable`1 splitPlanID)
 at PX.Objects.AM.CriticalMaterialsInq.CreateLinkedProductionOrders(AMProdItem prodCreatedFrom, CreateProdFilter filter, ProdMaint prodMaintGraph, Numbering numbering, Int32 level, List`1 ordersList)
 at PX.Objects.AM.CriticalMaterialsInq.CreateLinkedProductionOrders(AMProdItem prodCreatedFrom, List`1 ordersList)
 at PX.Objects.AM.ProdMaint.<>c__DisplayClass107_0.<CreateLinkedOrders>b__0()
 at PX.Concurrency.CancellationIgnorantExtensions.RunWithCancellationViaThreadAbort(Action method, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at PX.Concurrency.CancellationIgnorantExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ToCancellationViaThreadAbort>b__0(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at PX.Concurrency.Internal.PXLongOperationPars.PopAndRunDelegate(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at PX.Concurrency.Internal.RuntimeLongOperationManager.PerformOperation(PXLongOperationPars p)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
 at PX.Concurrency.Internal.PXThreadPool.RunItem(RequestItem item)
 at PX.Concurrency.Internal.PXThreadPool.Run()
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()


I would on the persist of the production order child orders on insert if there is a parent reference, query to the parent and get the qty to produce and set it.

Hi @Brendan I have updated my code to a row inserting event. I still receive errors saying no reference related to ProdMaintRecord found. Could you please review?

What is ProdMaintRecord? I would think you just need to query AMProdItem.

Yes I believe row inserting event handler does not facilitate the copying of values to the child order, the override method I have coded gives me the error which I have added in the post, is there any reason why this happens?

extending CreateLinkedOrdersDelegate and updating multiple AMPRodItem records in the same graph instance will have problems. I would avoid that. I would stick with RowInserted (or if parent values not there then RowUpdated when cache status is inserted)

Thanks for the suggestion Brendan, in this case for the rowinserted event handler I just have to remove the reference to ProdMaintRecords as it is invalid?  I have also modified my event handler above.

I would not call update in an event handler. I would just set the values using cache.SetValueExt<>(). Is the ParentOrdID available in RowInserted? if not might also need this in RowUpdated. I would also query on keys. Suggest using AMProdItem.PK.Find(Base, OrderType, ProdOrdID) in place of PXSelect.

Hi Brendan thank you for your suggestions, I've updated my code as per your advice. Could you please have a look and verify?

Are you getting an error? I would also check for cache status of AMProdItem is inserted as your code will keep running over and over again.

It does work as expected and I'm not getting any errors in the trace as well.
